# Nativescript application builds fine for android but not for IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript, xcode11

Here is the logs I get when I try to build ios:

```
Project successfully prepared (ios)
Configure firebase
Building project...
Xcode build...
/Users/me/Desktop/vt/vt_tv/front/Native/App/platforms/ios/Pods/ASBPlayerSubtitling/ASBPlayerSubtitling/ASBPlayerSubtitling.m:41:1: warning:
      method possibly missing a [super awakeFromNib] call [-Wobjc-missing-super-calls]
}
^

// Then I get a long list of my icon resources

warning: 'UILaunchImages' has been deprecated, use launch storyboards instead. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
error: cannot parse the debug map for '/Users/me/Desktop/vt/vt-tv/front/Native/App/platforms/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app/App': Is a directory
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/rsync.c(244) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Comment: I think I renamed App to the name of my app and in turn renamed my entitlements file and the reference to it in my build config and the problem was resolved. can somebody tell me why that was? Do I have to use the app name for the name of the directory?

Comment: Yes, the app name is always the directory name. If you want to change the app's display name though you may give your own name in info.plist (`CFBundleDisplayName`), the project name / entitlements etc., will still use the directory's name.

Comment: @Manoj I did this because I have two apps for two different countries that are branded totally separately but share most of the code. Now that you say this I guess I should rename the name of this directory too before building, could you please tell me what else depends on the name of this file? so far I know the name of the entitlements file and there referneces to that file.